# Hive add partition data change

Tags: hive

If I have regular table in Hive named employees and it contains the following data

```
/tab1/employeedata/file1
id, name, dept, year
1, gopal, TP, 2012
2, kiran, HR, 2012
3, kaleel,SC, 2013
4, Prasanth, SC, 2013
```

After I add a partition by year Hive will create new files as such

```
/tab1/employeedata/2012/file2

1, gopal, TP, 2012
2, kiran, HR, 2012

/tab1/employeedata/2013/file3

3, kaleel,SC, 2013
4, Prasanth, SC, 2013
```

My question is that after adding the partition, will my original file1 get deleted? If not, does that mean if I add several different partitions my data will be the original size times the number of partitions?

Thanks,

Comment: Partitions are subsets of your data. The sum of the size of the partitions equals the original size of your data.

Comment: Also whether your file will be deleted depends on if you are using an external table.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.